# PHP - loop through messages in array

Tags: php

I have weird problem with my PHP code. I decoded an elasticsearch json, and I got this array:

```
Array ( [took] => 1 [timed_out] => [_shards] => Array ( [total] => 6 [successful] => 6 [skipped] => 0 [failed] => 0 ) [hits] => Array ( [total] => 7336 [max_score] => 0.8790647 [hits] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [_index] => logstash-2019.02.25 [_type] => doc [_id] => 5T8GJWkBAZbF3w3t4NF2 [_score] => 0.8790647 [_source] => Array ( [@version] => 1 [log-level] => ERROR [port] => 50906 [host] => 6b14cd1f183d.mynetwork [@timestamp] => 2019-02-25T14:20:01.367Z [Timestamp] => 2019-02-25T13:57:40+0000 [message] => Array ( [0] => 2019-02-25T13:57:40+0000 ERROR something happened in this execution. [1] => something happened in this execution. ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [_index] => logstash-2019.02.25 [_type] => doc [_id] => 7z8GJWkBAZbF3w3t4NF2 [_score] => 0.8790647 [_source] => Array ( [@version] => 1 [log-level] => INFO [port] => 50906 [host] => 6b14cd1f183d.mynetwork [@timestamp] => 2019-02-25T14:20:01.369Z [Timestamp] => 2019-02-25T14:00:13+0000 [message] => Array ( [0] => 2019-02-25T14:00:13+0000 INFO takes the value and converts it to string. [1] => takes the value and converts it to string. ) ) ) ) ) )
```

What I want is only to print the "messages".

If I run this code:

`$echo json_decoded['hits']['hits']['0']['_source']['message']['0']`

It echo `"2019-02-25T13:57:40+0000 ERROR something happened in this execution."`

And if I run this code:

`$echo json_decoded['hits']['hits']['1']['_source']['message']['0']`

It echo `"2019-02-25T14:00:13+0000 INFO takes the value and converts it to string."`

ALL GOOD SO FAR, but now I want to run it as loop, to print the messages. I made the following loop:

```
foreach($json_decoded['hits']['hits'] as $host) {
    echo $host[$index]['_source']['message']['0'];
    $index++;
}
```

I don't get any output. What is the problem?

Comment: Try removing `[$index]` from `$host[$index]['_source']['message']['0'];`

Comment: OMG so simple... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you foreach over `['hits']['hits']` this will iterate over the next level of the array (so the `['0']` and `['1']` elements).  So you don't need to add in the `[$index]` part of your `echo` or the `$index` value...

```
foreach($json_decoded['hits']['hits'] as $host) {
    echo $host['_source']['message']['0'];
}
```